# UTF8 encoding of multi-byte characters in C/Assembly

Tags: c, assembly, utf-8

I've a C program that looks like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
int main(void){
setlocale(LC_ALL,"en_US.utf8);
printf("%ls",(const wchar_t*)L"\u20AC\n");
}
```

The disassembled version is this:

```
.file   "ok.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "en_US.utf8"
    .align 4
.LC1:
    .string "\254 "
    .string ""
    .string "\n"
    .string ""
    .string ""
    .string ""
    .string ""
    .string ""
    .string ""
.LC2:
    .string "%ls"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
```

The UTF-8 octal code for my input, the €(EUR. Symbol) is    '\342\202\254'. Why is only '\254' that shows and why are the rest whitespaces (excluding new line)? Without the L directive I get nothing printed as well and the asm output is something like `.string '\343\202\254'?

Comment: `L"\u20AC\n"` creates a wide character string, not a multibyte string.  To create a multibyte string you'd have to use `"\u20AC\n"` (without the `L` prefix) and hope either UTF-8 is the default execution character set, or somehow tell the compiler that you want it to be.  Using `setlocale` won't do this, as it's only executed at runtime, when its too late to tell the compiler anything.

Comment: You made a mistake pasting your code.  Please fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L""` and `wchar_t` is not utf8 in your environment, it looks like utf32. So due to endianness I expect your 4 byte `wchar_t` values to be:

```
0xAC, 0x20, 0x00, 0x00  ; this is your \u20AC
0x0A, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  ; this is the \n
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  ; this is the end of string
```

The compiler used the fact that `0x20` is a space in ascii and that `.string` emits a zero byte automatically, so:

```
.string "\254 "  ; 0xAC, 0x20, 0x00
.string ""       ; 0x00, so now you have your \u20AC
.string "\n"     ; 0x0A, 0x00
.string ""       ; 0x00
.string ""       ; 0x00, so now you have the \n
.string ""       ; 0x00
.string ""       ; 0x00
.string ""       ; 0x00
.string ""       ; 0x00, so now you have the terminating zero
```

Comment: Where does "\254" come from, though?

Comment: `\254` is octal for `0xAC`.

Comment: Oops, thanks a lot! one last thing though, how could you tell this is UTF32 encoding and not UTF8? And could you explain what exactly happens when it gets assembled like '\342\202\254' (in the case of no L")?

Comment: Without `L` it uses whatever encoding your compiler is set to. For you that **is** utf8 and so those 3 bytes are the utf8 values.

Comment: I am curious though, without L I get nothing printed. Why is that?

Comment: `%ls` still expects a utf32 wide string and your utf8 data represents `0x0AAC82E2` which is outside of currently defined characters. Probably followed by more invalid characters until you accidentally hit 4 zero bytes signalling end of string.